# How do I get the selected value of a DropDownList in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I get the selected value from the DropDown in MVC? I want to assign it to a variable.

This is my controller action:

```c#
public ActionResult Drop()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Horror", Value = "4" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Art", Value = "5"  });
    ViewData["Options"] = items;
}
```

This is my view:

```c#
@Html.DropDownList("Options", ViewData["Options"] as SelectList, "--Select Item--")
```

Comment: During page view (ie, react whenever the selected value is changed), or after form submit?

Comment: When do you want the selected value to be stored in the variable? In the post method, or in the method you mentioned above? The latter isn't possible (and also, I see no reason why anyone should need that value. It will always be the first element.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <h2>Drop</h2>
    @Html.DropDownList("Options", ViewData["Options"] as SelectList, "--Select Item--")

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Controller**
Add a new action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Drop(FormCollection form)
{
    var optionsValue = form["Options"];
    //TODO:
    return RedirectToAction("Drop");
}
```

Comment: also wat in the functionality difference between html.dropdownlist and html.dropdownlistfor

Comment: `Html.SomeControlFor(model=>model.Property)` is used to create a html control for the `Property`. Then you can use a strong-typed parameter in your post-back Action, like `public ActionResult Drop(ModelType entity)`

Comment: thanku, but now for the same list i used in my post, if i want to user @html.dropdownlistfor(), wat changes do i need to make?

Answer (score 3):

Also, consider that if you are not using FormCollection in your post, you could easily use the following, this is very helpful especially if you are using partial views inside the main one.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Drop(SelectListItem item)
{

    var selectedValue = Request.Form["ID_OF_THE_DROPDOWNLIST"];
    //TODO......
    return RedirectToAction("Drop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <fieldset>
        Select filter
        @Html.DropDownList("SelectFilter", @Model.ddlList)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller :

```
        public ActionResult Index(string SelectFilter)
        {
            var _model = new Models.MyModel();

            List<SelectListItem> listDDL = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listDDL.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "11", Value = "11" });
            listDDL.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "22", Value = "22" });
            listDDL.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "33", Value = "33" });
            ViewData["ddlList"] = listDDL;

//We add our DDL items to our model, you can add it to viewbag also
//or you can declare DDL in view with its items too
            _model.ddlList = listDDL;
            return View();
        }
```

Model :

```
Public class MyModel
{
     public List<SelectListItem> ddlList = new List<SelectListItem>();

}
```